# Why can't I share my printer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have **Windows 7** installed on two computers.

I can share folders between them **fine**.

However, I **can't seem to share printers** between them: when I right-click on the printer I expect to see "**share printer**" but there is no option for that.

[image]

When I read about "share printers" in the Windows 7 help, it talks about this computer "not being able to connect to a **home network**", yet they seem to be connected fine (I can share files between them).

**Why can't I share printers between the computers if I can share files?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Printer Properties, then check the Sharing Tab

Comment: Per @hanzie's answer, look at @Edward's image above.  Now *don'*t click on the printer's "Properties" menu item at the end, click on its "Printer Properties" menu item in the middle.  The sharing tab is in that one.  Nice user experience design, Microsoft!

Answer (score 6):

FOUND IT!

There are **2 properties** in the right click menu.  I have no clue why, but there are.

Right click, **go to printer properties**, NOT properties.  They're both listed on mine, anyway.

There's the sharing tab, right there.

[image]

Comment: +1: This was my version of the problem.  Solutions elsewhere said to click on "Properties", adding to the confusion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had Cannon MF3240 with the same problem. Right after Windows 7 x32 update and installation of Symantec Endpoint security I could not find the "SHARING TAB". After one hour circling  around and messing up with the "homegroup and network sharing" options I went back to:

Start / Devices and Printers / right click on the printer / Printer Properties / Sharing (Second Tab)

... and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a HomeGroup? IIRC you can specify sharing of printers when you join the HomeGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start 
 -> Printers and devices 
 -> Printer in question 
-> Customize printer -> Sharing tab -> Share this printer.